# AMLS compute: Notebooks on VM

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Can anyone please help me understand the following:

1. Can you run two separate notebooks powered by two separate computes/VMs? 
   I've tried running two notebooks on separate VMS on AMLS workspace portal, it always selects the same VM for each notebook. Is this possible?
2. If using the same VM compute on AMLS to run multiple notebooks, does it use a separate core within the VM to run each notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback. Yes you should be able to do (1), we are fixing that. Thanks